# mysql - Using variable in where clause stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

im newbie in Stored Procedure. 
I have simple example of my problem, in SP, I wrote this

```
BEGIN
DECLARE totalRows INT;
START 
    SELECT count(cont.contentCode) INTO totalRows FROM ms_content as cont WHERE entityCode = 'ACAW';
    SELECT totalRows;
COMMIT;
END
```

I call it, success. I want to add condition where clause in variable. So I change my code to:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE totalRows INT;
START TRANSACTION;
    SET @aa = concat("entityCode = 'ACAW'");
    SELECT count(cont.contentCode) INTO totalRows FROM ms_content as cont WHERE @aa;
    SELECT totalRows;
COMMIT;
END
```

SP return zero rows. Its possible to store condition in variable and put it in SELECT code?
Thank you.

Comment: You cannot parametrize **entire** WHERE clause. To do that you could use `dynamic SQL` but it will be quite dangerous and vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. [SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE @condition](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Condition) - SQL Server but idea is the same

Comment: Read up on prepared statements here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html